# ¿Cómo aplicar minification utilizando la guía de estilos de angular de John Papa?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Cuando ***"minifico"*** el código javascript utilizando angular.js ¿Qué técnica debe aplicarse para inyectar las dependencias?

A continuación expongo la dos formas:

**Forma normal**

```
var app;
app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController',['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

   //Procesos a ejecutar

}]);
```

**Jhon Papa Style**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('miControlador', miControlador)

 function miControlador(){

   //Proceso a ejecutar

 };
```

Comment: No entiendo tu consulta. ¿Cuál es tu duda? Lo único que veo es que en lugar de asignar el resultado de `angular.module('myApp', [])` a una variable y luego llamar el método en esa variable llama el método sobre el resultado de llamar a esta función.

Comment: como pasas $scope o $http, o cualquier otra palabra reservada del framework utilizando la guia de John Papa a eso me refiero, si te fijas en la forma normal se pasan como variables primero para que cuando al minificar la cambien el nombre no exista ningun error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La guía de estilo de John Papa a la que se refiere [Pedro Miguel Pimienta Morales](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2896/pedro-miguel-pimienta-morales) está publicada [aquí](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) y es muy interesante y recomendable.

El problema que se comenta en la pregunta hace referencia a la regla de estilo [Y024](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y024) donde John Papa recomienda usar funciones con nombre en vez de funciones anónimas:

```
/* avoid */
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('DashboardController', function() { })
    .factory('logger', function() { });

/* recommended */
// dashboard.js
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('DashboardController', DashboardController);

function DashboardController() { }

// logger.js
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('logger', logger);

function logger() { }
```

Unida a esta buena práctica, [está esta otra](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#manual-annotating-for-dependency-injection) que hace referencia a como gestionar las dependencias:

```
/* avoid - not minification-safe*/
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('DashboardController', DashboardController);

function DashboardController(common, dataservice) {
}

/* avoid */
angular
.module('app')
.controller('DashboardController',
    ['$location', '$routeParams', 'common', 'dataservice', Dashboard]);

function Dashboard($location, $routeParams, common, dataservice) {
}

/* recommended */
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('DashboardController', DashboardController);

DashboardController.$inject = ['$location', '$routeParams', 'common', 'dataservice'];

function DashboardController($location, $routeParams, common, dataservice) {
}
```

**Recomendación:** Si se pretenden seguir las buenas prácticas de John Papa hay que leérselas completas porque están relacionadas entre ellas

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda @rsciriano, de verdad que me he saltado un par de cosas, esto era lo que buscaba, espero que de esta forma al minificar no presente problema alguno

Answer (score 3):

Cuando hablas de inyección de angular a la hora de minificar solo puedes usar 2 de las 3 formas de inyección de angular, usando la notación de arreglo o la propiedad `$inject`.

**Notación de arreglo**

```
angular.module('nombreModulo')
    .controller('nombreController', ['dependencia1', 'dependencia2', definicionDelController]);

function definicionDelController(dependencia1, dependencia2) {

}
```

Esta notación muchas veces acostumbra a usarse usando una función anónima lo cual es muy problemático cuando hay muchas dependencias.

```
angular.module('nombreModulo')
    .controller('nombreController', [
        'dependencia1', 
        'dependencia2', 
        'dependencia2', 
        function (dependencia1, dependencia2, dependencia3) {

     }]);
```

Como puedes ver esto se puede salir de control rápidamente si el controller o servicio(mejor llamado *inyectable* para estos propósitos) que estas implementando es medianamente complejo. Puede ser más legible o no **depende del caso** en cuestión.

**Usando $inject**

Esta es la forma de anotación más simple(incluso internamente el camino del algoritmo usado por angular para inferirlos es el mas rápido) ya que simplemente angular retorna el arreglo que le pasas cada vez que el servicio `$injector` llama a la función `annotate`.

```
angular.module('nombreModulo')
    .controller('nombreController', definicionDelController)

// Esto activa esta forma de inyección
definicionDelController.$inject = ['dependencia1', 'dependencia2'];

function definicionDelController(dependencia1, dependencia2) {

}
```

Esta es la variante recomendada por John Papa y la razón de esto no es que las demás sean más malas sino que esta notación tiene muchas ventajas **cuando se usa en combinación con los demás puntos de su guía**:

1. Inyección automática([Y100](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y100) y [Y101](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y101))

   John Papa usa un servicio llamado [`ngAnnotate`](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) que se encuentra en una tarea de [`gulp`](https://github.com/Kagami/gulp-ng-annotate) o [`grunt`](https://github.com/mgol/grunt-ng-annotate) que hace precisamente esto:

   Cuando encuentra una función con un comentario `/*@ngInject*/` revisa los argumentos de esa función y le agrega una propiedad `$inject` a la función (recuerda que todas las funciones en javascript pueden tener propiedades al igual que los demas objetos) con las dependencias que requiere tu inyectable. De esta forma puedes escribir tu código sin anotarlo en development y cuando minifiques y hagas un build las inyecciones serán colocadas automáticamente.
   Si usas notación de arreglo será un poco más complicado ya que tienes que indicarle a `ng-annotate` que la función es inyectable usando una cadena de caracteres en el cuerpo de la función con `"ngInject";` lo cual puede omitirse muy fácilmente creando una gran cantidad de errores en el build.
2. Uso de funciones ([Y024](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y024))

   John Papa usa declaraciones de función en lugar de expresiones de función o funciones anónimas para estructurar todo su código. Ve mi respuesta en https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/4572/2224 para que entiendas las diferencias entre las dos cuando se hace hoisting. Según su guía este patrón es el recomendado

   ```
   /* recommended */

   // dataservice factory
   angular
       .module('app.core')
       .factory('dataservice', dataservice);

   dataservice.$inject = ['$http', '$logger'];

   function dataservice($http, logger) {
       //...
   }
   ```

   Como puedes ver la función que define el controller se le pasó al módulo a pesar de estar declarada debajo lo que te permite separar el bloque de la definición y te permite leer mejor cuales son sus dependencias. Se puede leer de esta forma:

   `módulo->nombre del inyectable->dependencias->implementación`

   En contraste esto es más difícil de leer ya que el nombre del inyectable se confunde con sus dependencias.

   ```
   /* avoid */

   // dataservice factory
   angular
       .module('app.core')
       .factory('dataservice', ['$http', 'logger', dataservice]);

   function dataservice($http, logger) {
       //...
   }
   ```
3. Uso de $inject y dependencias ([Y091](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y091))

   El `ng-annotate` puede detectar cuando ya se ha hecho la inyección y no la repite, usar un `$inject` facilita este proceso ya que el `ng-annotate` usa esa misma técnica para especificar las dependencias.

   En las directivas los controllers son inyectables también; si revisas la guía esto puede ser un problema cuando pones una instrucción `return` antes de la declaración de tu función (*lo cual es un patrón muy usado en esta guía!!!!*) asi que usar un `$inject` puede ayudarte un poco ya que puedes mover *siempre* tu función de un lado a otro junto con sus dependencias lo cual no siempre es posible si usas notación de arreglo.

**Notación implicita**

Esta notación solo es recomendada en development ya que cuando minifiques tus dependencias serán renombradas y por ejemplo el servicio `$http` se puede renombrar a `a` o `b` lo cual hace que angular sea incapaz de encontrar el inyectable especificado; por esa razón John Papa no te la recomienda.

Para activar este modo solo debes pasar la definición de tu inyectable sin una propiedad `$inject` y sin usar un arreglo. Ej:

```
angular.module('nombreModulo')
    .controller('nombreController', definicionDelController);

function definicionDelController(dependencia1, dependencia2) {

}
```

Comment: Según lo que dices, si uso la notación implícita no podría minificar el codigo, debido a que generarian errores al no encontrar el nombre de las dependencias inyectadas?

Comment: Si usas minificación implicita y **no** usas una herramienta como ng-annotate (En el template de john papa ya viene por defecto en el gulp), si podrás minificar pero no te va a funcionar. Esta herramienta fue construida para que no tuvieras que preocuparte por las dependencias independientemente del tipo de notación que uses. Es buena practica habilitar la inyección de dependencias estricta con la directiva `ng-strict-di` y usar `$inject` para que no tengas sorpresas cuando hagas un build. Esta recomendación viene de la propia [documentación de angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Comment: Los minificadores se pueden configurar para que no renombren los nombres de los argumentos. Mira la opción `mangle` en [gulp-uglify](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify) y [Uglify2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#the-simple-way) pero todo eso se puede evitar creando el hábito de escribir `$inject` en tu código. La mayoría de los IDES soportan plantillas de código y John Papa incluye las suyas en [Y250-Y260](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#file-templates-and-snippets) así que puedes escribir tu código ya con las buenas prácticas incluidas ;)

Comment: Gracias, de igual manera pienso que lo ideal es evitar configurar algo que es lo que busco, pero no sabia eso, gracias por el datos.

Comment: Me faltó: J. Papa no es el único que tiene una guía de estilo; Todd Motto también tiene [una](https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-styleguide) que comparte algunas similitudes con la de J. Papa. Ambas tocan el tema de la minificación por exactamente las mismas razones. Me llamó la atención tu pregunta cuando escribiste **forma normal**, al final _todas_ son normales, excepto que en el momento que se escribió la guía usar `$inject` está de moda ;) Antiguamente la notación de arreglo era la moda y no hay nada de malo en ello :D

Comment: Gracias de nuevo, sabia de esa otra guía, lo que no entendía o no tenia conocimiento era lo de minificar usando esas guías, gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @devconcept  Una respusta muy completa. La guía de Todd Motto no la conocía, la he mirado por encima y se ve muy interesante, en algunos aspectos complementaria a la de John Papa. Lo que comentas de `$inject`, a parte de modas, viene muy bien cuando trabajas con *TypeScript* porque implementas una clase y yo el registro lo hago en otro archivo de código. Lo de usar `ngAnnotate` personalmente me parece un riesgo, prefiero los *Decorators* de *TypeScript*. Saludos //cc:@PedroMiguelPimientaMorales

Answer (score 2):

Si utilizas la herramienta `grunt` no necesitas la versión anotada para minificar, con escribir en la Jhon Papa y hacer `grunt build` ya se encarga de anotar y minificar el código.

Comment: Lo mismo ocurre si utilizo Gulp.js, o solo con grunt

Comment: No pasa por default, tienes que utilizar algo como ng-annotate https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-annotate tanto en grunt como en gulp.

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente el problema que se plantea se reduce a la definicion de los modulos que vas a inyectar el el controller.

[A Note on Minification](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#a-note-on-minification)

[Declaring AngularJS Modules For Minification](https://scotch.io/tutorials/declaring-angularjs-modules-for-minification)

Esta claro que si aplicas `minification` del código angular en el `Jhon Papa Style` no va a funcionar. Esto se genera porque angular usa los nombres de las variables para reconocer que debe inyectar, pero la minificacion cambia estos por otros impidiendo que angular resuelva las dependencias.

Recuerda que `minification` reduce el código acortando los nombre de las variables, funciones, etc cambiandolas por otras, lo cual altera los nombre de los parametro que defines al inyectar en el controller.

Distinto es el caso de la `Forma normal` ya que defines como string los modulos a inyectar, al aplicar la `minification` no cambia las cadenas de string por lo que angular puede usarlas para conocer que modulos mapean con que variables inyectar al construir el controller.

En resumen usa el `Forma normal` si vas usar `minification`.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda